# Window Functions and effiecient querying

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for certain information from canceled transactions...

```
What was the Next Transaction from that Canceled Transaction's Store 
What was the Next Transaction from that Canceled Transaction's Customer'
What was the Next Transaction from that Canceled Transaction's City
and so on and so forth...
```

I have millions and millions of Transactions
but only about 100,000 Canceled Transactions

Window Functions work great with this  as I use the LEAD() function and partition it by Store, Customer, City etc...

but I need to apply these Window functions to every Transaction (as Window functions only work with your result set)
then I have to filter all these Transactions and get (the info for) only my Canceled Transactions.

If I just bring in my Canceled Transactions and query for this Data (of temp tables)  - The Query seems less efficient and takes longer.

It seems however I do it the Window Functions perform better.

Is there a better way to do this then to apply Window Functions to ALL of my Transactions?  (then filtering for the Canceled ones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `outer apply`.  For instance, for the next for stores:

```
select nc.*, cstore.*
from (select c.*
      from transactions c
      where c.type = 'Cancelled'
     ) c outer apply
     (select top 1 nc.*
      from transactions nc
      where nc.type = 'NotCancelled' and nc.store = c.store and
            nc.datetime > c.datetime
      order by nc.datetime
     ) cstore;
```

This can use an index on `transactions(type, store, datetime)`.  If the logic for cancellation is more complicated, then you might need a computed column.

Adding additional dimensions is as simple as adding more `outer apply`s.  Try one first to see how the performance goes.

Comment: Neat solution but way inefficient.

Comment: I suspect  the problem is the order by in the outer applied table. This table needs all of that stores transactions then orders them to finally just give you the top 1.  Where as the Window function (albeit only within your Result Set) quickly gives you the Next Store's transactions. Despite the querying of extra records,

Comment: @Chobes . . . As a mention in the answer, this should actually be quite efficient with the right index.  It might be even *more* efficient than a version using window functions.

Comment: Implemented your Outer Apply. Excelent Solution.